# socket.io server doesn't work after deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, socket.io

I'm having trouble with connect to my socket.io server, I want user to be connected when on.connection, here's my server code

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');
const {getUserList, get_Current_User, user_Disconnect, join_User, playByTurn } = require("./dummyuser");
//Set static folder
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server, {
     cors: {
     origin: "http://localhost:8080",
     methods: ["GET","POST"]
                                }
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;



//Run when client connect
//Run when client connect
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(`Connected: ${socket.id}`);

   //Code

    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`Disconnected: ${socket.id}`);
       //Code
    })

});

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

On my localhost it works just fine, but after I deploy it said that it can't GET from my server, any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was finally solved it by adding   transports: ['websocket'] in my client code

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
 const socket = io("//url",{
         transports: ['websocket'],
        });
```